# jquery using .filter() to check two td:nth-child(x) conditions

Tags: jquery

I need to filter based on 2 conditions in jquery on a table and certain `td` contents. I can filter one, I am not sure how to filter based on two though. I need to filter both the 3rd `AND` the 8th `td` in one shot.

```
$('.searchable tr').filter(':has(td:nth-child(3):contains("Open"))').show();
```

This one filters only the third.

I know how to filter just based on class names like

```
$(selector).filter('.one, .two');
```

using OR and

```
$(selector).filter('.one.two');
```

using AND

But I am not sure how to combine mine since it is contained in `''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this scenario it would probably be easier to provide a function to `filter()` which executes the logic you require. Try this:

```
$('.searchable tr').filter(function() {
  var $tr = $(this);
  var $td3 = $tr.find('td:nth-child(3):contains("Open"))');
  var $td8 = $tr.find('td:nth-child(8):contains("Open"))');
  return $td3.length == 1 && $td8.length == 1;
}).show();
```

Comment: Had to go to doctors, was trying to get it to work but couldn't. I'll try a fiddle when I get back and let you know